# Cannot get default printer on remote computers

Tags: vbscript

I am using the bellow script to get the default printer name on remote computers. It works well on the local computer but when I try on a remote computer I get an error: Access denied Code: 80041003. I am using a domain administrator account. Could anybody let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = InputBox ("Enter Computer Name - blank will display information about this computer","Get Default Printer")
If strComputer = "" Then
  strComputer = "."
End If

sMethod     = "GetStringValue"
hTree       = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
sKey        = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows"
sValue      = "Device"


Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv")


Set oMethod = oRegistry.Methods_(sMethod)
Set oInParam = oMethod.inParameters.SpawnInstance_()

oInParam.hDefKey = hTree
oInParam.sSubKeyName = sKey
oInParam.sValueName = sValue

Set oOutParam = oRegistry.ExecMethod_(sMethod, oInParam)
strPrinter = oOutParam.Properties_("sValue")
strPrinter = Split(strPrinter, ",")(0)
MsgBox(strPrinter)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as current user (HKCU) on remote computers. HKCU is ALWAYS you on your computer. HKU\User is the way to access users on remote computers.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Thank you so much anyway